# Liquid Background

Tags: javascript, image, layout, background

I would like to have a liquid background on my website such as the one you can see on this website : 
http://www.baliilmare.com/

I used to have done it in the past using FLASH and actionscript 3 but it really seems dated as an option

and the max-width 100% CSS trick doesn't give the same result.

I actually would like to reap the Javascript from this website but am really noob in terms of javascript and would need a tut or maybe someone pointing the right JS/Jquery (I see different .js files used from the source)
I can then google it and see how it works ...

Can someone help ?

Comment: All this is is a css fixed background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firefox or Chrome and right-click->inspect element. It's the fastest way to see what's going on behind a site.

They are using the image as a cover.

HTML:

```
<div class="coverImg" style="background-image: url(urltoimage); height: 456px; ">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.coverImg {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
position: relative;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Is there no javascript involved here? can I just reap the CSS and have the same result ?

Comment: Ok I have googled background-size and seen all the options, from which "cover" :) That's a very good news this can be done via CSS. Had no knowledge of that. Many Thanks Michael.

Comment: Be sure to include the -webkit..., -moz..., -o... css properties for cross-browser compatibility. Glad to help!

Comment: Will do. and maybe have a look to all those CSS "hidden" options that now allows a lot

Answer (score 0):

you probably could load the background image into your body tag:

```
body { background-image: url(/images/thisbackground.jpg);
```

hope this helps